# Installing Ubuntu for future install windows 8.1

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, multi-boot, windows-installation

I want to install ubuntu on my asus zenbook ux32vd and then to install windows 8.1 alongside ubuntu

I have 500GB HDD and 24GB SSD

How I need to spread these disks for ubuntu/windows I mean what I need to do in gparted before linux install

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it depends on which OS you want to run faster. But with a 24 GB SSD you are very short in space. I would subjectively adivce the following, advantaging Linux :

- 20 GB SSD Partition for Linux OS
- 4 GB SSD SWAP Partition for Linux SWAP
- 80 GB HDD Windows Partition
- 420 GB HDD Data Partition for storing your datas

The 420 GB HDD Partition would host games, etc.

I would put Linux on the SSD because Windows requires a lot of space when you install various programs and I don't know if you intend on using massively Windows or Linux.

You can add an extra partition in the 420 GB HDD space left, that would complete the space missing on the SSD. But it won't run as fast the SSD when accessing or modifying it.

**EDIT : Advantaging Windows :**

- 24 GB SSD Windows Core
- 60 GB HDD Windows Programs
- 80 GB HDD Linux Programs
- 4 GB HDD SWAP
- 356 GB HDD Data Partition

Comment: I think I am ok with fast windows and slow linux :) I have 10 GB ram and I7 so I think for work its ok on Linux?

Comment: Yes it would. My suggestion is edited hereabove

Comment: As I understand you mean: 1. install windows to ssd + hdd 2. install linux ?

Comment: Yes, that is the way